# Highlight Current Player in Leaderboard Adapter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to inflate a card view layout with a RecyclerView adapter which will display a list of all the players with descending order of score.

I want that when a user opens the leaderboard section it should display all the users' score in cards but his card should be highlighted. How can I do that? Is it possible if I compare holder.textview with the current username?

Leaderboard Adapter:

```
public class LeaderboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LeaderboardAdapter.LeaderboardCustomViewHolder>{
Context mContext;
ArrayList< String> mArrayList =
        new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList< String> mArrayList1 =
        new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<GradientDrawable> mGradientDrawables;
String name;
public LeaderboardAdapter(Context context, ArrayList <String> arrayList,ArrayList<String> arrayList1){
mContext=context;
mArrayList=arrayList;
mArrayList1=arrayList1;
mGradientDrawables= new ArrayList<>();
fillGradientList(mContext);

FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
final String email = mFirebaseUser.getEmail();
final DatabaseReference ref;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

ref.child("quizz").child("Users").child(email.replace(".", "")).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);


}

@Override
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});


}
@Override
public LeaderboardCustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
final View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.players_list_view,parent,false);
return new LeaderboardCustomViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final LeaderboardCustomViewHolder holder, final int position) {

final String playerName=mArrayList.get(position);
final String playerScore=mArrayList1.get(position);
holder.playerTextView.setText(playerName);
holder.playerScoreView.setText(playerScore);

sort();

if(holder.playerTextView.getText().equals(name))
{
Log.d(TAG,"Current checkName:"+holder.playerTextView.getText().toString());
int color=mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.wrongAnswerBackground);
holder.playerCardView.setCardBackgroundColor();

new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {

notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}, 10);

}    
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArrayList.size();
}



public class LeaderboardCustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
private TextView playerTextView;
private TextView playerScoreView;
CardView playerCardView;
RelativeLayout playerRelativeLayout;
public LeaderboardCustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
super(itemView);
playerTextView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerTextView);
playerScoreView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerScoreView);
playerRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerRelativeLayout);
playerCardView=(CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.playersCardView);
}

}
}
```

Card View XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/playersCardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_64x"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_4x"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_16x"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_4x"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_8x">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/playerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/fab_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playerTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_4x"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused"
            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16x" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playerScoreView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```